# Menu bars on Palette windows don't work properly -- any workarounds?

Tags: front-end, windows, palettes, version-10, menu

After getting help from Rojo with [Menu commands on Palettes and other windows without menu bars?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54599/121) I was able to create a Palette with a menu bar by:

1. Selecting the Palette and opening the **Option Inspector** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
2. Setting `Editable -> True` and `WindowElements -> {"MenuBar"}`

However the bar seems very glitchy:

- Sometimes it appears to be entirely disabled
- Then when I drag the window around or change focus a time or two it comes to life
- Then later becomes disabled again
- Sometimes it appears to be enabled (not grayed out) but I can't open any of the menus

Further the menu commands themselves, when available, don't work right:

- Despite confirming that `Saveable -> True` the **Save** and **Save As...** items are disabled
- The **Palettes** > **Generate Notebook from Palette** item is also disabled; if not usable *here* then where?

Though I could not **Save** the Palette (Notebook) I captured its expression with [`NotebookGet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookGet.html):

```
Notebook[{Cell[
   BoxData[ButtonBox["\"Beep!\"", Appearance -> Automatic, ButtonFunction :> Beep[], 
     Evaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"]], "NotebookDefault"]}, 
 Editable -> True, WindowSize -> {700, 100}, 
 WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 51}, {266, Automatic}}, WindowFrame -> "Palette", 
 WindowElements -> {"MenuBar"}, WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "MinimizeBox"}, 
 FrontEndVersion -> "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 1, 2014)", 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Palette.nb"]
```

#### Are other Windows users able to reproduce the series of bugs I described above?

#### Has anyone figured out how to work with Palettes in Version 10 under Windows?

Comment: (ahem) some of us are still using older versions of the software.

Comment: @bobthechemist I'm not sure how to take that comment.  I did tag the question `version-10`; do you think I should also have put that information at the top of the post?  Or if you mean something else: as a long-time Version 7 user I am highly sympathetic to those who are not running the latest version, but as the community saw fit to pay for my copy of Version 10 and I am doing my best to learn and analyze it.

Comment: Bob thought he would be among the first to receive the new version, but I take it he still hasn't got his copy. So, see this as a semi jealous/hopeless/desparate/funny remark. Nothing to worry about. Sometimes you just take life too seriously :) BTW can't test right now. The iPad version of v10 hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: On my phone so can't test this but pretty sure the problem is due to settings in the palette.nb stylesheet. I think you need to create a private stylesheet

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sjoerd is correct; my comment was meant to be taken humorously.

Comment: I tried the Notebook expression in 10.0 under Windows 8.1 x64. The menubar looks fine and I can *save as* it properly. But the *Generate Notebook from Palette* item is disabled everywhere. Maybe try `NotebookSave`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, any News on that Topic?

Comment: @Louis No, I have not learned anything new.  Sorry.