# How can I edit the built-in Stylesheets in Mathematica?

Tags: stylesheet

It seems that the default stylesheets used by Mathematica's Front End cannot be edited like other user-created stylesheets. The following, for example, is the stylesheet for the Help documents of Mathematica:

```
hlpst = $InstallationDirectory <>"/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Wolfram/Reference.nb"
```

After being opened, it looks like a usual stylesheet window, **except** that its contents (such as font colours) cannot be edited at all.

So my question is: How can the stylesheet *Reference.nb*, in the folder shown above, be edited in a stylesheet window, just as a user-created stylesheet can?

Comment: Here's an example where I modified the Palette.nb: [Menu commands on Palettes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82712/5478). Is that enough?

Comment: See [Working with Stylesheets](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html) and Related Tutorials.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. It works!

Comment: @Kuba That seems like a rather narrow example even if the method can be applied generally.  Can you find any other Q&A's that are more general?  If so we can dual-close (both linked in the header).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think there was something better but I've failed to find it.