# Change the default package toolbar?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, packages, stylesheet, docked-cell

Everytime a package file (.m or .wl), it opens with the standard package toolbar (a docked cell)

```
DockedCells->FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
 "FEExpressions", "BuiltInStylesheetToolbar"]
```

What is a simple way to change this default to some other custom cell?

Comment: Establish given stylesheet in $UserBaseDirectory, like in: [**82712**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82712/5478), and edit it.

Comment: Here's another topic, where some other changes were applied to Package.nb stylesheet: [80995](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80995/5478). Is that enough?

Comment: @Kuba what is the file called?

Comment: Which? Package editor stylesheet? It seems it's `Package.nb`, take a look at `CopyFile` line there.